# Contextual type 'Void' cannot be used with dictionary literal

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

This Error comes up after I relaunched my Project without any changes, never heard of it before.

```
func toDictionary() -> [String : Any] {

    let newPostRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()
    let newPostKey = newPostRef.key

    // 1. save image
    if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(newPostKey)")

        storage.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: { (snapshot) in
            self.downloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

        return [ <- The Error appears here!!!
        "text" : text,
        "imageDownloadURL" : downloadURL,
        "numberOfLikes" : numberOfLikes,
        "numberOfDislikes" : numberOfDislikes
    ]
        }
    )}
}
```

Maybe the following lines of Code help, as I only read something that this Error occurs because of any false String or something like that...

```
var text: String = ""
private var image: UIImage!
var downloadURL: String?
var numberOfLikes = 0
var numberOfDislikes = 0
let ref: DatabaseReference!

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot){
    ref = snapshot.ref
    if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
        text = value["text"] as! String
        downloadURL = value["imageDownloadURL"] as? String
        numberOfLikes = value["numberOfLikes"] as! Int
        numberOfDislikes = value["numberOfDislikes"] as! Int
    }
}
```

Comment: You are inside the closure of `observer()` which is async. That won't work. You need to use yourself a closure and manage correctly the asynchronism. Look for "Swift + Closure + Async".

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the Firebase function `observe` is asynchronous, so you cannot use the synchronous `return` statement to return values from it. You need to declare your function to use a completion handler.

```
func toDictionary(completion: @escaping ([String:Any])->()) {

    let newPostRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()
    let newPostKey = newPostRef.key

    // 1. save image
    if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(newPostKey)")

        storage.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: { (snapshot) in
            self.downloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            let snapShotDict = ["text" : text, "imageDownloadURL" : downloadURL, "numberOfLikes" : numberOfLikes, "numberOfDislikes" : numberOfDislikes ]
            completion(snapShotDict)
        }
    )}
}
```

Then access it like this:

```
toDictionary(completion: { dict in
    // You can only use `dict` inside the completion handler closure
    print(dict)
})
```